# AppendTo Not Working On Webpage

Tags: jquery, appendto

I have this jQuery script:

```
$('.company').each(function(i, item) {
  var tempTitle = item.title;
  $('Working').appendTo("div[title='" + tempTitle + "']");
});
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<li><div class="company" title="32"></div><div class="shortdescription">Short Description Here</div></li>
<li><div class="company" title="33"></div><div class="shortdescription">Short Description Here</div></li>
<li><div class="company" title="34"></div><div class="shortdescription">Short Description Here</div></li>
<li><div class="company" title="35"></div><div class="shortdescription">Short Description Here</div></li>
<li><div class="company" title="36"></div><div class="shortdescription">Short Description Here</div></li>
```

and no details are added in the divs.

Where is the mistake I make? O_o

Comment: Your selector is wrong, `$('Working')` selects `<Working>`. However you are trying to move the same element(s) in each iteration that doesn't makes sense, and your markup is invalid.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to insert a  simple string 'Working' for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendTo` requires HTML or jQuery wrpped element to append. You are passing simple string **working**.

Try this:

```
$('.company').each(function(i, item) {
  var tempTitle = item.title;
  $('<div>appeded by jQuery</div>').appendTo("div[title='" + tempTitle + "']");
});
```

Now replace `<div>appeded by jQuery</div>` with the HTML you want to append.

Comment: The other way around should support text nodes: `$("div[title='" + tempTitle + "']").append('Working')`

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of keeping it simple - the OP's code looks like it may be machine generated so he can rely on the structure staying the same

So:

```
$('.company').each(function(i, item) {
  $(this).next().append('Working');
});
```

Would work if that is the case.

or

```
$(this).next('.shortdescription').append(' Working');
```

to be safe